# next.js middleware, NextResponse.redirect() not working when using map or foreach, but it works when using for loops

Tags: next.js, middleware

//this won't work

```
rules.filter(rule => rule.type === 'redirect' && new RegExp(rule.rule).exec(pathname.slice(1)))
    .map(rule => { 
        console.log('match');
        const url = req.nextUrl.clone()
        url.pathname = rule.destination
        return NextResponse.redirect(url)
    })
```

//this does work

```
for (let rule of rules) { 
        const regex: RegExp = new RegExp(rule.rule)
        if(regex.exec(pathname.slice(1)) && rule.type === 'redirect') {
            console.log('match');
            const url = req.nextUrl.clone()
            url.pathname = rule.destination
            return NextResponse.redirect(url)
          }
        }
```

the middleware is already running well with de for loop

Comment: `map` is probably not the function you want to use in this scenario. Try using `forEach` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Reddit gave me the solution, I leave it here

A return statement inside `map` simply adds to the map output array.

A return statement in a for loop exits the function.

Next.js will redirect if a middleware returns NextResponse.redirect(), as you would if you used a for loop and return statement.

```
 let result
    rules.filter(rule => rule.type === 'redirect' && new RegExp(rule.rule).exec(pathname.slice(1)))
    .map(rule => {
    console.log('match');
    url.pathname = rule.destination
    result = NextResponse.redirect(url)
    })

return result
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks man, I had the same problem with NextResponse, your answer save me.

Answer (score 0):

Can reproduce this issue. We had to convert:

```
  PRIVATE_ROUTES.forEach((route) => {
    if (url.pathname.includes(route)) {
      if (!authenticated) {
        url.pathname = Routes.auth.signIn;
        return NextResponse.redirect(url);
      } else if (
        req.cookies.get('auth-next-url') &&
        url.pathname !== req.cookies.get('auth-next-url')
      ) {
        url.pathname = req.cookies.get('auth-next-url')!;
        return NextResponse.redirect(url);
      }
    }
  });
```

To this:

```
  for (let route of PRIVATE_ROUTES) {
    if (url.pathname.includes(route)) {
      if (!authenticated) {
        url.pathname = Routes.auth.signIn;
        return NextResponse.redirect(url);
      } else if (
        req.cookies.get('auth-next-url') &&
        url.pathname !== req.cookies.get('auth-next-url')
      ) {
        url.pathname = req.cookies.get('auth-next-url')!;
        return NextResponse.redirect(url);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I've a schema of chain middlewares, like this

```
[withAuthentication, withAccessToken, withUser, ...]
```

And, my `middleware.ts` file is like this

```
const middlewares = [withAuthentication, withAccessToken, withUser, ...]
export default pipeMiddleware(middlewares)
```

NextResponse.redirect works on first middleware, but not work on second, middleware because the first middleware call the second like this

```
export const withAuthentication: MiddlewareFactory = (next: NextMiddleware) => {
  return async (request: NextRequest, _next: NextFetchEvent) => {
    ...

    next(request, _next)
  }
}
```

Instead of is:

```
export const withAuthentication: MiddlewareFactory = (next: NextMiddleware) => {
  return async (request: NextRequest, _next: NextFetchEvent) => {
    ...

    return next(request, _next)
  }
}
```